# Good open source iOS games?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios, objective-c

I would like to see how things are done in modern iOS games, I am especially interested in Cocos2D games.
I need a game that will compile (warnings are ok) and since most of the project I have seen fail with errors that I can't fix, I decided to ask here.
Maybe someone knows some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two books that have complete games for cocos2d in them.  Both books seem to take slightly different but equally valid approaches to game design with cocos2d.

Learn Cocos2d Game Development with iOS 5, by S. Itterheim and A. Low.

Learn Cocos2d: A Hands-on Guide to Building Games with Cocos2d, Box2d, and Chipmunk, but R. Strougo and R. Wenderlich.

Answer (score 0):

[Fabien Sanglard](http://fabiensanglard.net) has released an engine/game of his written in C. It's not exactly AAA quality, but it runs and compiles on all major platforms (iOS and Android included). He has quite a few writeups describing various aspects of it, including why he chose C. You can find it [here](http://fabiensanglard.net/shmup_android/index.php).